Vue 3 reactivity issue with class instance as vue component attribute
I tried to make a popup manager for manage multiple popup opening (so if i can close a popup the previous one will reopen automatically and request for the data that it needs to work).
The issue is about the v-if directive that doesn't trigger when I click on the card related to the popup. I print the v-if condition in a console log and it shows it's true but the popup doesn't open.
This is the code for the popup and the popup manager:
class Popup {
    private key: string
    public show = false
    public title: string
    private icon: string
    public data = null
    public loading = false
    private permission: boolean
    private params: iObject = {}

    constructor(key: string, title: string, permission: boolean, icon = '', defaultData: any = null) {
        this.key = key
        this.title = title
        this.icon = icon
        this.permission = permission
        this.data = defaultData
    }

    toString = () => this.title

    getKey = () => this.key
    isShow = () => this.show
    getTitle = () => this.title
    getIcon = () => this.icon
    getData = () => this.data
    isLoading = () => this.loading
    getPermission = () => this.permission
    getParams = () => this.params

    setTitle = (title: string) => this.title = title
    setPermission = (permission: boolean) => this.permission = permission
    setParams = (params: iObject) => this.params = params

    isVisible = () => this.show && this.permission

    open = (loading = true): Popup => {
        this.show = true
        this.loading = loading
        return this
    }
}

class PopupManager {
    public popups: Popup[] = []

    add = (popup: Popup) => {
        if (this.findPopup(popup.getKey()) !== null)
            return
        this.popups.push(popup)
        console.log('Popup added:', popup)
    }

    remove = () => {
        this.popups.pop()
        if (this.isOpen())
            this.popups[this.popups.length -1].open()
    }

    isOpen = () => this.popups.length > 0

    getPopup = (): Popup | null => this.isOpen() ? this.popups[this.popups.length -1] : null

    getPopupByKey = (key: string): Popup | null => {
        const popup = this.getPopup()
        return popup !== null && popup?.getKey() === key ? popup : null
    }

    findPopup = (key: string): Popup | null => {
        return this.popups.find(popup => popup.getKey() === key) || null
    }
}

and this is the component that use the popup manager:
<script lang='ts'>
import {defineComponent, defineAsyncComponent} from 'vue'

import {iUsersData, iEventData, iProfileRequest, iSocketResult, iColors, iBookingContent, iObject} from '@/utils/interfaces'
import {Dark} from '@/utils/palette'
import { Device, Role, urlProfile, AccountActions, ProfilePagesGuest, ProfilePagesUser, ProfilePagesAdmin, ProfilePagesNamesGuest, ProfilePagesNamesUser, EmitActions, Errors, ProfileActions, Messages, ProfilePagesNamesAdmin, Status, profilePopups} from '@/utils/constants'
import {defaultProfilePopup, defaultBookingPopup, defaultProfilePopups} from '@/utils/default'
import {checkObject, checkString, Popup, PopupManager} from '@/utils/functions'

import TemplateView from '@/views/Template.vue'

const ProfilePopup = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/ProfileManage.vue'))
const AccessPopup = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/Access.vue'))
const CouponPopup = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/Coupon.vue'))
const Card = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/cards/Card.vue'))
const ConfirmPopup = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/Confirm.vue'))
const SvgIcon = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/buttons/Svg.vue'))
const BookingUpdate = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/BookingUpdate.vue'))
const BookingRecap = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/Booking.vue'))
const BookingsManage = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/BookingsManage.vue'))
const UsersManage = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/UsersManage.vue'))
const UserUpdate = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/UserUpdate.vue'))
const ForgotPassword = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/ForgotPassword.vue'))
const RestorePassword = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/popup/RestorePassword.vue'))

export default defineComponent({
    extends: TemplateView,
    inheritAttrs: false,
    name: 'ProfileView',
    components: {
        ForgotPassword,
        TemplateView,
        ConfirmPopup,
        ProfilePopup,
        AccessPopup,
        CouponPopup,
        Card,
        SvgIcon,
        BookingUpdate,
        BookingRecap,
        BookingsManage,
        UsersManage,
        UserUpdate,
        RestorePassword,
    },
    props: {
        colors: {
            type: Object as () => iColors,
            default: Dark,
        },
        device: {
            type: Number,
            default: Device.Desktop,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        profilePopups: () => profilePopups,
        popups: function (): Popup[] {
            return [
                new Popup(profilePopups.Confirm, '', true),
                new Popup(profilePopups.Access, 'Login', this.userData?.role === Role.Guest, 'login'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.Profile, 'Profilo', this.userData?.role !== Role.Guest, 'profile'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.Bookings, 'Prenotazioni', this.userData?.role !== Role.Guest, 'bookings'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.EditBooking, 'Modifica prenotazione', this.userData?.role !== Role.Guest),
                new Popup(profilePopups.Coupon, 'Coupon', this.userData?.role !== Role.Guest, 'coupons'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.Users, 'Utenti', this.userData?.role === Role.Admin, 'users'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.UsersBookings, 'Prenotazioni utenti', this.userData?.role === Role.Admin, 'list'),
                new Popup(profilePopups.UserUpdate, 'Modifica utente', this.userData?.role === Role.Admin),
                new Popup(profilePopups.ForgotPassword, 'Password dimenticata', true),
                new Popup(profilePopups.RestorePassword, 'Ripristina password', true),
            ]
        },
        popupManager: () => new PopupManager(),
    },
    data() {
        return {
            profile: {
                socket: null as unknown as WebSocket,
                attempts: 0,
                connected: false,
                restart: true,
            },
            pages: Object.values(ProfilePagesGuest),

            popups_: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultProfilePopups)),
        }
    },
    methods: {...},
    watch: {
        userData() {
            this.setProfileData()
        },
        'userData.role'() {
            this.setPages()
            this.popups_['Profile'].data.role = this.userData?.role
        },
        'userData.identifier'() {
            if (checkString(this.userData.identifier)) {
                this.initProfileSocket()
            }
        },
        'settings.visible'() {
            if (this.settings.visible) {
                clearTimeout(this.timers.socket)
            }
            else
                this.timers.socket = window.setTimeout(() => {
                    try {
                            this.profile.socket.close()
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            //pass
                        }
                }, this.halfMinute)
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setPages()
        if (checkString(this.userData.identifier)) {
            this.initProfileSocket()
        }
        this.setProfileData()
        this.initRequests()
    },
    unmounted() {
        this.profile.restart = false
        try {
            this.profile.socket.close()
        }
        catch (e) {
            // pass
        }
    },
    emits: [EmitActions.Account,]
})
</script>

<template>
    <TemplateView>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <div
                class='Profile'
            >
                <Card
                    v-for='popup in popups.filter((p) => p.getPermission() && p.getIcon())'
                    height='30vh'

                    :key='popup.getKey()'
                    :colors='colors'
                    :label='popup.getTitle()'

                    @click='popupManager.add(popup.open()); this.$forceUpdate()'
                >
                    <SvgIcon
                        size='90px'
                        :effect='false'

                        :icon='popup.getIcon()'
                    />
                </Card>
            </div>
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <ConfirmPopup
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.Confirm)?.isVisible()'

                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :action='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.action'
                :params='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.params'
                :colors='colors'

                @confirm='confirmAction'
                @close='popupManager.remove()'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <AccessPopup
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.Access)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @action='getActionAccount'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <ProfilePopup
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :defaultData='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()'

                @action='getActionAccount'
                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <CouponPopup
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.Coupon)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :defaultData='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :role='userData.role'
                :isLoading='popupManager.getPopup()?.isLoading()'
                :lines='Math.ceil(popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.count/4)'
                :max='Math.ceil(popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.count/4)*4'

                @action='getActionAccount'
                @close='popupManager.remove()'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <BookingRecap
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.Bookings)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :bookings='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.bookings'
                :role='userData.role'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :isLoading='popupManager.getPopup()?.isLoading()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @cancelBooking='cancelBookingRecap'
                @error='sendMessage'
                @active='getRecapBookingData'
                @edit='openEditBookingRecap'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <BookingUpdate
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.EditBooking)?.isVisible()'

                :booking='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :role='userData.role'
                :colors='colors'
                :isViewOnly='false'
                :device='device'

                @editBooking='editBooking'
                @close='popupManager.remove()'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <BookingsManage
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.UsersBookings)?.isVisible()'

                :bookings='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.bookings'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :isLoading='popupManager.getPopup()?.isLoading()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @search='searchBookings'
                @error='sendMessage'
                @cancelBooking='cancelBookingUsersBookings'
                @edit='openEditBookingUsersBookings'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <UsersManage
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.Users)?.isVisible()'

                :users='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()?.users'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :isLoading='popupManager.getPopup()?.isLoading()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @edit='openEditUser'
                @getDetails='getDetails'
                @search='searchUsers'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <UserUpdate
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.UserUpdate)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'
                :isLoading='popupManager.getPopup()?.isLoading()'
                :user='popupManager.getPopup()?.getData()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @editUser='editUser'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <ForgotPassword
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.ForgotPassword)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @action='getActionAccount'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
        <Transition name='popup'>
            <RestorePassword
                v-if='popupManager.isOpen() && popupManager.getPopupByKey(profilePopups.RestorePassword)?.isVisible()'

                :colors='colors'
                :device='device'
                :title='popupManager.getPopup()?.getTitle()'

                @close='popupManager.remove()'
                @action='getActionAccount'
                @error='sendMessage'
            />
        </Transition>
    </TemplateView>
</template>

<style scoped lang='scss'>
@import '@/assets/styles/views/Profile';
</style>

I tried by creating some computed properties for the v-if directive like:
isPopupOpen: function () {
   console.log('isPopupOpen')
   return this.popupManager.isOpen()
},

but it's called at page load but not when I click on the card

Don't use arrow methods or other functions created inside a constructor. I'd advise to not use classes at all with reactivity as this leads to problems like this one. The same code could be expressed with plain objects, and computeds would be more preferable than getter functions
